# How do you limit root to no more than 1 login at a time?

Tags: ssh, users, root, user-management

I took a practice test for a cert and one of the questions was "Limit root to no more 2 simultaneous logins, make this configuration persistent between restarts". I didn't even really know this was possible. Is this just for ssh or could you do this for all terminal access on the machine? If so, how?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: ...Nobody really, "runs" Ubuntu. They let GRUB bootstrap it, and fight with it, until they can afford a Mac.

Comment: @knotech Well, I could afford one, bought a System76 and then went ahead and installed Arch. So I suppose you're right. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to limit the terminals through which root login is allowed. This is done by editing [`/etc/securetty`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/securetty.5.html). Just let `securetty` contain any two TTYs and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` and add:

`root hard maxlogins 1`

This will limit the total number of root login shells to 1, and it includes both local and remote access.

Comment: I tested that before posting the `securetty` answer. Doesn't work (and the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/limits.conf.5.html) says as much - `except for this with uid=0`.)

Answer (score -1):

Nevert tried this but would go the following way:

1. Make `bin/bash` and other shells unaccessible to root.
2. Create script that would run bash if not already running, otherwise exit.
3. Assign this script as root shell.

Comment: "Make bin/bash and other shells unaccessible to root." What does that mean?

Comment: Edit the rights.

Comment: It would work (therefore upvote) It would also be very dangerous...  ;-)